# Radio value retrieval

Tags: javascript, html

I do not believe there is a getElementByValue() method but is there a way of retrieving the "Yes" value in my form?

```
<form>
    Do you work at Mori Seiki? <br />
    <input type ="radio" name = "group1_answers" value = "Yes" /> Yes <br />
    <input type ="radio" name = "group1_answers" value = "No" /> No <br />
    <input type ="radio" name = "group1_answers" value = "Perhaps" /> Perhaps <br /> 

    Your answer is: <input type ="text" id = "work_answer" />
    <script>
        if(document.getElementByValue('Yes')){   <-- similar function?
            ;
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) should do the trick:

```
var radioButton = document.querySelector('input[value="Yes"]');
```